# How to connect to MS SQL using PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, database-connection

I have a PHP script that uses the following code:

```
$con = mssql_connect('192.168.152.2\webservice','sa','p@$$w0rd') or die('Could not connect to database server');     
mssql_select_db('mydatabase') or die('Could not connect to Database');
```

I need to run this script on 2 machines. One server works ok, another doesnt.

Ok, here’s a few things I know/tried:

- Both machines already connect to a MSSQL database. They have
  php5-sybase library installed.
- I’m convinced there aren’t any restrictions to the sa user that is used to connect to both – in terms of hosts it can connect from.

Things I don't know how to check/or could influence things:

- Even though both machines have same php libraries. Do they have same version of library?
- Number of concurrent connections a MSSQL user can have on the box.
- The box that cant connect is running PHP Version 5.2.4 (however can connect to another MS SQL database)

I dont know what I'm missing. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [`sqlsrv` extension](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Try mssql_get_last_message.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php

Comment: your connection string is correct.  may be other server host is different than `192.168.152.2\webservice`

Comment: Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 192.168.152.2\webservice in /var/www/intranet/htdocs/test.php on line 6

Comment: The connection string works fine from a different machine on the network. I have another PHP script connecting to a different MS SQL on the machine that this is failing on. That's the head scratcher...

Comment: so it might be user name or password problem

Comment: are all computers using the same OS?

Comment: The same script runs from another machine fine, with the exact same username/password. The machine that connects fine is using Ubuntu 11.04. The machine thats failing is using Ubuntu 8.04.4

Answer (score 0):

What about the host IP addresses ? They must be different right ?

Machine No.1 works since it must be associated with 192.168.152.2 , other machine must have a different ip. So try the IP associated with Machine No.2

Comment: There's 3 machines involved here. One with a database on it: 192.168.152.2. Anther machine where the script works ok from 192.168.152.10 and another machine which im trying to connect from but its failing 192.168.152.9

Answer (score 0):

Both server have different IP.

So try other server host IP.

Just change the host of new server it will work fine.

```
$con = mssql_connect('192.168.152.2\webservice','sa','p@$$w0rd') or die('Could not connect to database server');     
mssql_select_db('mydatabase') or die('Could not connect to Database');
```

just change `192.168.152.2\webservice` to other server host.

Comment: But I want to connect to 192.168.152.2\webservice

Comment: But the same script runs from another machine fine, with the exact same username/password